# Unable to retrieve selected dropdownlist value of ASP.NET webform in C# .cs file

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to access selected dropdownlist data in .cs file but unable to fetch same. I am fetching data in dropdownlist from mysql database.

.aspx code:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddrc_name" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="155px"></asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:Button ID="display_btn" runat="server" Text="Display" Height="37px"  Width="125px" OnClick="display_btn_Click" />
```

.cs code:

```
protected void display_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rc_name =  Request.Form["ddrc_name"];
    String category = "Painter";

    Response.Redirect("~/dispay_rate_card.aspx?rc_name="+rc_name+"&category="+category);
}
```

How can I fetch selected dropdown data in .cs file from webform?

Comment: `ddrc_name.Value` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var selectedText = rc_name.SelectedItem.Text;
var selectedValue = rc_name.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: Hi Luciano Thanks but I did tried this one as well still not getting expected value.
As I mention I am fetching data in dropdownlist from mysql database-

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select distinct rc_name from rate_card", con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);

            ddrc_name.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["rc_name"].ToString();
            ddrc_name.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["rc_name"].ToString();
            ddrc_name.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddrc_name.DataBind();
ddrc_name.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Rate Card Name", "0"));

Comment: so if i try var selectedText = rc_name.SelectedItem.Text; ==> showing value as Rate Card Name and if try var selectedValue = rc_name.SelectedItem.Value;  ==> getting value 0

Comment: But not which i am selecting in webform

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping.
I am able to fetch DropDownList selected data from Webform if I directly create webform rather than using Master template.

String dd = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];

If I am creating webform using master page then unable to fetch selected data of DropDownList.